# Swiper element scaling on hover, overflow hidden problem

Tags: html, css

I use swiper in my project. Each swiper elements is scaling on hover. But content is cutting because of overflow hidden. I can't give padding or height because of the design. How can I fixed it?

Comment: Hello, it would greatly help if you could recreate your problem using a code snippet in your question.

Answer (score 2):

- As we know by default `.swiper-container` has property set to `overflow:hidden`.
- To overcome the problem of content being cut off we first need to set `.swiper-container{overflow:visible}`.
- As soon as we set `.swiper-container` to `overflow:visible` all the `.swiper-slide` will become visible, which is not what we want.
- We just need `.active` swiper slide and `previous` and `next` slide to visible.
- So in swiper slider we have classes already comes with `.swiper-slide`, which is `.active`(currently active slide),`.swiper-slide-next`(for next slide) and `.swiper-slide-prev`( for previous slide).
- By default slides has `opacity:1` and `visibility:visible`, but making overflowing content of `.swiper-container` makes every slide visible, so to set current,next and previous slide visible we can see default slide class, which is `.swiper-slide` to `opacity:0` and `visibility:hidden`, and then:

````css
// CSS to set current,next and previous slides visible and accesible.
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active,.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-next,.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-prev{
opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
- We will set **current**,**next** and **previous** slide to visible
- Now when we scale or hover visible slides it's content won't get cut off as ```.swiper-container``` has ```overflow:visible``` and only desired slides are visible and scaling them will not cut their content.
````

```css
.swiper-container {
    overflow: visible;
}
.swiper-slide{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active,.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-next,.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-prev{
opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but instead of scaling the active slide, you could also just scale down the `not-active` slides, giving the illusion that the middle, centered slide is bigger. Nexo's solution did not work for me. Here is my code in React:

```
export default function TemplateCarousel() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-200 py-24">
      <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto lg:px-10 md:px-6 px-8">
        <Swiper
          modules={[Pagination]}
          spaceBetween={60}
          slidesPerView={3}
          centeredSlides={true}
          pagination={{ clickable: true }}
          loop={true}
          breakpoints={{
            768: {
              slidesPerView: 3,
            },
            480: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
            },
          }}
        >
          <SlidePreviousButton />
          {slides.map((slide) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={slide.previewImg}>
              {({ isActive }) => (
                <img
                  src={slide.previewImg}
                  className={clsx("w-full h-full rounded-md transition-transform", {
                    "scale-90 transition-transform": !isActive,
                  })}
                />
              )}
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
          <SlideNextButton />
        </Swiper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```